# The detail of RGBDSLAMv2

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2, rgbdslam-freiburg, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I download a copy of RGBDSLAMv2 and successfully run on my computer, it is amazing. So I am have a lot interest in it and decide to analysis the code. It seeming not that easy even thought I download the paper "3D Mapping With an RGB-D Camera". So I ask for some help, some detail information or a tutorial, or how this code works and the architecture may help me a lot.
may thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191352/the-detail-of-rgbdslamv2/) by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Linbo Jin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20093/linbo-jin/) on 2014-08-27**:
Are you working on Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS hydro?

**Comment by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on 2014-08-27**:
Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS Hydro. I just want to know the detail of the rgbdslam.

**Comment by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on 2014-08-27**:
Yeah, I have know the website. And I have read this papers, but it seems hard to me. You can understand all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Felix has published all the papers about the RGBDSLAM, so you can find all papers on his side: [http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~endres/](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Eendres/)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0